# Not equal to in a do while loop

Tags: java

For some reason a sentinel value will not work as expected

```
public static int play() {
        String input;int result;
        do {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to play-Enter 1 if yes , 0 if no");
        result = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } while (result != 1 || result != 0);
        return result;
    }
```

This code above never works but it works just fine if i change the condition from `while (result != 1 || result != 0);` to `while (result < 0 || result > 1);`

Why is that so and how can i make not equal work in a `do...while` loop in java ?

Thanks

Comment: In college, my professor said that "coding by brownian motion" is the root of all evil.  Seek to understand why your program is doing anything at all rather than approaching it from the perspective of: "When I move this over there, the program behavior is changed".  While the program isnt right, make a random change, retest.  When complete, submit assignment.  BAD programmer!  no biscuit.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMorgansLaws.html

Comment: `while(true)` with `if(result == 1 || result == 0) break;` is far more readable IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
while (result != 1 && result != 0) {...}
```

This will execute the code, ONLY if `result` is NOT `0` or `1`

---

In your example, the boolean statement in the `while` loop will ALWAYS be equal to `true` because result can be equal to only 1 value:

```
while (result != 0 || result != 1)
```

If `result` is `1`, then it is not equal to `0`, if it is `0`, then it can't be `1`, so it will ALWAYS be `true`

Comment: Explanation? I get it is a simple answer, but an explanation of why this works would help for the people of the future who don't know how JOptionPane works

Comment: It has nothing to do with "how JOptionPane works" and is simply a matter of boolean logic. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMorgansLaws.html

Comment: Works fine so it was just a logic error ...Your explanation is awesome

Comment: @user2650277 Thanks. Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

`while (result != 1 || result != 0)`

This condition means it will always loop even with '1' or '0' as a response:

If the user enters 0, which should be valid, it will satisfy `result != 1` and return `true`.

If the user enters 1, which should be valid, it will satisfy `result != 0` and return `true`.

---

You need to use `while (result != 1 && result != 0)`.

This will loop only if the answer is both not equals to 1 and not equals to 0.